# Why does wbadmin fail after a few days and report "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation"?

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012-r2

I have three Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard servers running on Dell PowerEdge machines that serve as Hyper-v hosts for my various virtual machines.   Each server has a scheduled backup similar to the following:

[image]

Notes:

- Each scheduled backup is configured to be a "VSS Full Backup".
- Some backups show the VMs as online and some show as offline.

The issue is that the backups will run for several days successfully and then will stop running.   After the backups begin to fail, I see the following when I open Windows Server Backup tool.

[image]

I also see Event 19 in the event log when the scheduled backup runs:

- The backup operation attempted at
  '?2018?-?06?-?04T02:00:01.583169900Z' has failed to start, error code
  '0x8007000E' ('Ran out of memory'). Please review the event details
  for a solution, and then rerun the backup operation once the issue is
  resolved.

If I attempt to run the backup using the wbadmin command line, I see the following error:

- Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.

If I sign out and then sign on, the issue is immediately resolved and I can see the backup history in the Windows Server Backup tool.   The backup will run again for several days until the issue occurs again.

The cycle of the issue on the three machines is very similar.  In other words, the backup will run successfully on all three machines for 2 days and then fail on all three machines and continue to fail until I sign in, sign out and then sign in on each machine.

Note: After verifying that the server backup is running with a sign in, sign out & sign in.  I typically sign out again.

Notes

- Each Hyper-v Server has 16 GB of free memory after the memory dedicated to the VMs is subtracted from the total memory.
- Each Hyper-v Server has 25 GB of free hard drive space on the C drive and 500 GB or more of free space on the D drive where the VMs are stored.
- Each backup drive has 1 TB of free space.

Any ideas?

I originally posted this question on Microsoft Technet.

[Technet Question](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/37e47e79-ff32-4251-a971-488a22aa574d/wbadmin-fails-immediately-and-reports-quotnot-enough-storage-is-available-to-complete-this?forum=windowsbackup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of this issue was the Bomgar Jump Client version 17.1.4.   After disabling the Jump Client, we have not experienced the issue.   See the linked Technet Question for more detail.